websocket with pekko/akka http TextMessage streamed vs strict
I had a thorough look at the doc as well as the code base but couldn't figure out how the size of the incoming message determined whether a message was Strict or Streamed.
Is it a websocket standard, a conf parameter or none of that? What's that size value?
